# Spring Forms - How to Check for Error on Specific Path

Tags: jsp, spring-mvc

I'm using the Spring Form library to handle a search page in my application.  Here is a snipped from my DD showing the bean configuration:

```
<bean name="/search.html" class="myapp.web.AccountSearchController">
        <property name="sessionForm" value="true"/>
        <property name="commandName" value="searchAccounts"/>
        <property name="commandClass" value="myapp.service.AccountSearch"/>
        <property name="validator">
            <bean class="myapp.service.AccountSearchValidator"/>
        </property>
        <property name="formView" value="accountSearch"/>
        <property name="successView" value="accountSearch"/>
    </bean>
```

The validator class is quite simple:

```
package myapp.service;

import org.springframework.validation.Validator;
import org.springframework.validation.Errors;

import org.apache.commons.logging.Log;
import org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory;

public class AccountSearchValidator implements Validator {

    /** Logger for this class and subclasses */
    protected final Log logger = LogFactory.getLog(getClass());

    public boolean supports(Class clazz) {
        return AccountSearch.class.equals(clazz);
    }

    public void validate(Object obj, Errors errors) {
        AccountSearch accountSearch = (AccountSearch) obj;
        if (accountSearch == null) {
            errors.rejectValue("domainName", "error.accountSearch.neither-specified", null, "Value required.");
        } else if (accountSearch.getAccountId().isEmpty() && 
                   accountSearch.getDomainName().isEmpty() ) {
            errors.rejectValue("domainName", "error.accountSearch.neither-specified", null, "Value required.");
        }
    }
}
```

In my JSP, my form is displayed in an HTML table.  I want field specific errors to be displayed under the respective field as a separate table row.  Here's a snippet:

```
            <tr>
                <td align="right" valign="top"><form:label path="domainName">Domain Name</form:label>:</td>
                <td><form:input path="domainName" size="30"/></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                 <td>&nbsp;</td>
                 <td><form:errors path="domainName" cssClass="error"/></td>
            </tr>
```

The question I have is - how can I make the output of the error row conditional on the existence of the error?  Is the Validator instance accessible from my JSP?  What would the test be for a c:if tag?

Thanks,

-aj

Answer (score 38, accepted):

OK it took me a few days but I figured it out:

```
    <c:set var="domainNameErrors"><form:errors path="domainName"/></c:set>
    <c:if test="${not empty domainNameErrors}">
        <tr>
             <td>&nbsp;</td>
             <td>${domainNameErrors}</td>
        </tr>
    </c:if>
```

This article was very helpful:
http://forum.springsource.org/archive/index.php/t-51044.html

Answer (score 7):

Use `<spring:hasBindErrors name="loginPasswordForm">`

Answer (score 5):

Use `<spring:bind path="fieldName">` and check `status.error` to see if the field has error

Example

```
<spring:bind path="phoneNumber">
     <form:input path="phoneNumber" />
     <form:errors path="phoneNumber" cssClass="error" />
     ${status.error ? 'has error' : ''}
</spring:bind>
```

Note

`<form:input path="" />` must be inside `<spring:bind >` tag

Comment: How can we use this method for paths? What if I declare `<spring:bind path="modelAttribute" />` at the start of the form, how will this be used for individual paths?

Comment: What I found is form:inputs must be inside `<spring:bind >` tag. Which means for each path you need to define `<spring:bind path="attribute">`

Answer (score 3):

Please check this code segment

```
<spring:bind path="domainName">
  <c:if test="${status.error}">
    <tr>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td><form:errors path="domainName" cssClass="error"/></td>
    </tr>
  </c:if>
</spring:bind>
```

Answer (score 3):

Actually there is a simple solution.
I haven't seen it anywhere but it seems to me that it is the simplest one.

```
<tr>
    <td align="right" valign="top"><form:label path="domainName">Domain Name</form:label>:</td>
    <td><form:input path="domainName" size="30"/></td>
</tr>
<form:errors path="domainName">
<tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td><form:errors path="domainName" cssClass="error"/></td>
</tr>
</form:errors>
```

When the form:errors tag has no body it renders the error with the default mecanism, but when the tag has a body, it just renders the body if there is an error for that path.

Comment: This seems to work in servlet environment, but fails in portlet environment. Still investigating though, see my question http://stackoverflow.com/q/35596690/637423