# Spring MVC - How to set parent div's class when there are validation errors?

Tags: jsp, spring-mvc, jsp-tags

Are there any ways to bind arbitrary element's css class to model bind state?

```
<form:form method="post" commandName="authForm" action="authenticate">
  <div id="login-error" class="control-group">
    <label>Login</label>
    <form:input path="name" />
    <span class="help-inline"><form:errors path="name" /></span>
  </div>

  <div class="control-group">
    <label>Password</label>
    <form:input path="password" />
    <span class="help-inline"><form:errors path="password" /></span>
  </div>

  <input type="submit" />
</form:form>
```

In this piece of code I need to manage `login-error`'s class to `control-group` when there are no errors and `control-group error` when there are (the same idea for second `control-group`).

What's the common solution here?

**Update**

Here's what I need when there's no bind error:

```
<div class="control-group"> <!-- !!!!!!!!!!!! -->
  <label>Login</label>
  <form:input path="name" />
  <span class="help-inline"><form:errors path="name" /></span>
</div>
```

Here's what I need when there is a bind error:

```
<div class="control-group error"> <!-- !!!!!!!!!!!! -->
  <label>Login</label>
  <form:input path="name" />
  <span class="help-inline"><form:errors path="name" /></span>
</div>
```

Looking for solution.

Comment: Can you please more elaborate your question. I am not able to understand your problem.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1653438/spring-forms-how-to-check-for-error-on-specific-path

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here's the solution that just works, but I'm not sure if it's really good idea:

```
<%@taglib prefix="spring" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags"%>
...
<form:form method="post" commandName="authForm" action="authenticate">
  <spring:bind path="name">
    <div class="control-group <%= status.isError() ? "error" : "" %>"
      <label>Login</label>
      <form:input path="name" />
      <form:errors path="name" cssClass="help-inline" />
    </div>    
  </spring:bind>
  ...
</form:form>
```

Comment: This could also be the nice solution. But according to me mixing the java code in jsp is very dirty and not recommended. Still for urgent solutions this work.

Comment: You can use the JSTL's ternary operator instead of injecting Java code, e.g.: `${status.error ? 'error' : ''}`.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and I solved it using jQuery.

```
<div class="control-group">
    <form:label path="groupCode" cssClass="control-label"><spring:message code="lookUp.groupCode"/></form:label>
    <div class="controls">
        <form:input path="groupCode"/>
        <form:errors path="groupCode">
            <form:errors path="groupCode" cssClass="help-inline"/>
            <script type="text/javascript">
                $("#groupCode").parent().parent().addClass("error");
            </script>
        </form:errors>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not able to find out a proper(common) solution here. But you can go with JavaScript and try finding if there is a span rendered in the view with id "name" or not and on base of this condition you can achieve what you want.

Because when there is no bind error for the specified  it would not generate the span tag for the same. And if there is an error for "name" then it will generate the respective span tag with the its id.

Hope this help you.
Cheeers.