# Spring errors tag, show additional errors

Tags: java, spring, jsp, tags

I have a password field defined in  JSP

```
<form:password path="userprofile.password" id="password"  />
```

`form` taglib refers to Spring form taglib (http://www.springframework.org/tags/form)

The JSP form contains other fields as well e.g. .

```
<form:input path="userform.name"  />
```

Since this is a password, even if user has provided valid password, it disappears on page reload.

Consider this scenario:
User has provided a valid password, but there is an error in "Name" field. on submit, page reloads and the error for "Name" is displayed, and password field is emptied out.

I want to show a message to user that the entered password is emptied due to security reasons and the user needs to enter that as well.

However, if the error is in password field itself, this additional message should not be shown.

Please suggest a solution.

PS:
I tried the solutions at [Spring Forms - How to Check for Error on Specific Path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1653438/spring-forms-how-to-check-for-error-on-specific-path)

They work for all fields apart from password, where I want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could not find a way to do the same in JSP. However, at spring controller (when the form was submitted) I used the following code  to make it work:

```
if (!errors.hasFieldErrors("password")){
    errors.rejectValue("password", "My Error Message Key....");
}
```

PS:
`errors` is the instance of `org.springframework.validation.Errors` which we get from Spring framework.